# Is it possible to 'not print a dictionary based on the values?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement, printing

I have a dictionary and would like to know if it's possible to "not print" the dictionary if there is a given value:

This is my dictionary:

```
    d={'Port':'1/0/1','Link-Status':'Down', 'Vlans':'None'}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to check the Values in the dictionary, and in this example, if  Vlans is 'None', don't print the dictionary.

I tried doing a 'for' condition, but it's  not working at all:

```
for v in d.items():
if v is not 'None':
    print(d)
```

This is what I'm getting from that output:

```
{'Port': '1/0/1', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': 'None'}
{'Port': '1/0/1', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': 'None'}
{'Port': '1/0/1', 'Link-Status': 'Down', 'Vlans': 'None'}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for k,v in d.items():
    if k =="Vlans" and v!="None":
        print(d)
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for the given input. Hope it helps you.

```
d={'Port':'1/0/1','Link-Status':'Down', 'Vlans':'None'}

count= 0

for key in d.keys():
    if d[key] is not 'None':
        count += 1
if count == len(d):
    print(d)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if d['Vlans'] != 'None':
    print(d)
```